# Using env variables in curl -o- request

Tags: shell, curl

I have a file in a remote server that has the following content:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

EMAIL=$1

echo "Test" && echo "Email: $EMAIL"
```

I'm executing:

```sh
curl -o- https://link-to-file/file.sh | bash email@example.com
```

Expected results:

```sh
Test
Email: email@example.com
```

Actual results:

```sh
(23) Failed writing body
```

Is that possible to do? send variables to a shell file in a remote server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few attempts I finally got to a solution.

```sh
bash <(curl -s https://link-to-file/file.sh) email@example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing the pipe to include the name of your script:

```
curl -o- https://link-to-file/file.sh | bash /dev/stdin email@example.com
```

Comment: What would be that /path/to/script? I dont have any script, the script I'm executing is the one being downloaded through curl. All I want to do is execute the remote file passing the email variable to it.